# What Field type to use when setting up new Content Type

Tags: nodes, feeds

I am setting up a new content type to use with Feeds.

I've selected a Field type of text for the Date label. Is that acceptable? The date will never be entered via the user interface. Instead, it will be pulled in from the csv file using Feeds.

Comment: It's as acceptable as you need it to be really. If that works for your purposes, great :) Personally I'd install the Date module so the data has some structure, but if it's never going on the front end, and you control everything that interacts with that field so the format is always predictable, I can't see you having any problems

Comment: Thank you!!!

I will install the Date module, since the Date column will be displayed in the search results.

Comment: Also, for the business number field I initially selected interger, but then the Widget only gives me the Text field option, not sure if that makes any difference, but I assume it would?

Also, the interger filed type only allows for a maximum of 10 characters, and I need it to be at least 11... Is it simplier to just use the Text field type?

Comment: A text type would be better, then you can deal with special characters/extension numbers etc. Or there's the [Phone module](http://drupal.org/project/phone) if you want a bit more structure